# Create a rectangular patch with upper and lower edge in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend-properties

I have the following plot in matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

x=np.linspace(0,2.,100)
y1=np.power(x,2)*2.+x
y2=np.power(x,2)*2-0.2

plt.plot(x,y1,color="k")
plt.plot(x,y2,color="k")

plt.fill_between(x,y1,y2,facecolor=(0,0,0,0.3),lw=0)
```

and I want to add a legend similar to this:

```
legend_elements = [Patch(facecolor=(0,0,0,0.4), edgecolor='k',
                         label='Filled area')]
plt.gca().legend(handles=legend_elements)
```

Which produces this:

[image: Plot with filled area]

However, I would like to remove the lateral edges from the patch in the legend, to match what I see in the plot (i.e., I only have the upper and lower edge).

I searched how to draw only some edges of a matplotlib patch but did not find anything. Is something like this possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [make your own legend handler](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#implementing-a-custom-legend-handler) by extending the built-in [`HandlerPolyCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_handler_api.html?highlight=handlerpolycollection#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerPolyCollection) which is used for `fill_between`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

x = np.linspace(0, 2., 100)
y1 = np.power(x, 2) * 2 + x
y2 = np.power(x, 2) * 2 - 0.2

plt.plot(x, y1, color="k")
plt.plot(x, y2, color="k")

plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, fc=(0, 0, 0, 0.3), lw=0, label="Filled area")

class HandlerFilledBetween(mpl.legend_handler.HandlerPolyCollection):
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle, xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans):
        p = super().create_artists(legend, orig_handle, xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans)[0]
        x0, y0 = p.get_x(), p.get_y()
        x1 = x0 + p.get_width()
        y1 = y0 + p.get_height()
        line_upper = mpl.lines.Line2D([x0, x1], [y1, y1], color='k')
        line_lower = mpl.lines.Line2D([x0, x1], [y0, y0], color='k')
        return [p, line_upper, line_lower]
    
plt.gca().legend(handler_map={mpl.collections.PolyCollection: HandlerFilledBetween()})
```

[image]

Comment: It looks exactly like what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it's possible to have different `edgecolor` values for the different edges in your patch. One possible workaround to get the result you want would be to set the `edgecolor` argument in the `Patch` to `None` and just plot two horizontal lines where your legend is. Below is an example of that:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

x=np.linspace(0,2.,100)
y1=np.power(x,2)*2.+x
y2=np.power(x,2)*2-0.2

plt.plot(x,y1,color="k")
plt.plot(x,y2,color="k")


plt.fill_between(x,y1,y2,facecolor=(0,0,0,0.3),lw=0)
legend_elements = [Patch(facecolor=(0,0,0,0.4), edgecolor=None,
                         label='Filled area')]

plt.gca().legend(handles=legend_elements,loc='upper center',frameon=False)
plt.hlines(y=10.1,xmin=0.735,xmax=0.87,color='k',lw=1.5,alpha=1)
plt.hlines(y=9.7,xmin=0.735,xmax=0.87,color='k',lw=1.5,alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: I was actually looking for a more automated solution, but you are indeed right that it is not possible to have different properties for the edges of a patch. So I guess your answer is the only possible solution and I marked it as accepted, even though I cannot really use it.